# Issues calling a function that accepts certain pointer types

Tags: c, pointers

I've finished some C Programming book and felt confident enough to try the cryptopals exercises. I wanted to call a libsodium function which excepts pointers to char arrays I can't figure out.

Could you tell me what is (obviously) wrong with my code and guide me a to a topic I can review to understand my problem?

```
int main() {
    unsigned char hex[] = "49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b652061207069736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d";
    const char *phex = hex;
    const size_t phex_length = sizeof(hex);

    unsigned char end[phex_length];
    const char ** const hex_end = &phex;
    
    printf("Using this hex string with size %ld bytes: \n %s \n",phex_length, **phex);
    
    unsigned char bin[phex_length*10];
    unsigned char * const pbin;
    size_t binsize = sizeof(bin);
    printf("sizeof result for bin: %d \n", binsize);
    

    int status = sodium_hex2bin(pbin, binsize, phex, phex_length, NULL, NULL, hex_end);
    if(status < 0) {
        printf("Error %d target: bin seems not large enoughi \n", status);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Converted Binary is: %d \n",bin);

    return 0;
}
```

The functions signature of libsodium I try to call (https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/helpers)

```
int sodium_hex2bin(unsigned char * const bin, const size_t bin_maxlen,
                   const char * const hex, const size_t hex_len,
                   const char * const ignore, size_t * const bin_len,
                   const char ** const hex_end);
```

Comment: "*what is (obviously) wrong*". Don't make us guess. Please tell us what error or incorrect behaviour is leading you to ask this question.

Comment: That is probably wrong: `const size_t phex_length = sizeof(hex);` The size of your string includes the terminating 0 byte. Also there is no need to make that `const` just because the functions signature marks it as `const size_t`.

Comment: The most obvious thing: you're ignoring your compiler warnings telling you `unsigned char bin[phex_length*10];` is clearly not a `int`, thus feeding it to `printf("Converted Binary is: %d \n",bin);` is nonsense, or your not enabling warnings telling you as much in the first place.

Comment: The purpose of `hex_end` is to report back the position where the conversion was ended. (Similar to purpose of `bin_len`. You should pass someting like this: `char *end; sodium_hex2bin(....., &end)`. You might revisit your text book about function parameters and calling by reference.

Comment: SO can only work properly if you give some feedback to comments or answers. If an answer helps solving your problem, you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should tell us what your problem is with your code. Also what compiler warnings yout get that you were not able to fix.

All this is missing in your question, but a few issues can already be seen:

```c
int main() {
    unsigned char hex[] = "49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b652061207069736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d";
    const char *phex = hex;
    const size_t phex_length = sizeof(hex);
```

The spec you linked tells us:

> hex does not have to be nul terminated, as the number of characters to parse is supplied via the hex_len parameter.

This means you should not include the terminating 0 byte.

Also why do you make `hex` an array of `unsigned char`? It is just a string and the functions expects `const char * const hex`. Nothing is telling you to make it unsigned.

```c
    unsigned char end[phex_length];
    const char ** const hex_end = &phex;
```

That is not a proper variable for the purpose it is used.
The function you call, will return the position where conversion stopped, to the caller via the `end` pointer. There is no point in passing the address of a `char[]`.

```c
  
    printf("Using this hex string with size %ld bytes: \n %s \n",phex_length, **phex);
    
    unsigned char bin[phex_length*10];
```

Where did you get the idea to allocate 10 bytes per hex digit?
Every 2 hex digits will end up in 1 binary byte.

```c
    unsigned char * const pbin;
```

Why make it `const`? That means you cannot even assign any value afterwards.

```c
    size_t binsize = sizeof(bin);
    printf("sizeof result for bin: %d \n", binsize);

    int status = sodium_hex2bin(pbin, binsize, phex, phex_length, NULL, NULL, hex_end);
    if(status < 0) {
        printf("Error %d target: bin seems not large enoughi \n", status);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Converted Binary is: %d \n",bin);
```

As mentioned in comment, `bin` is of wrong type for `%d`. And the value you are converting is way too large for any integer variable anyway.

```c
    return 0;
}
```

You seem to have completely misunderstood how function parameters work.
Check your textbook for passing by value and passing by reference (or passing by address)

With fixing the issues above your code should look more like that (untested):

```c
int main(void) {
    char hex[] = "49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b652061207069736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d";
    const size_t hex_length = strlen(hex);

    unsigned char *end;
    
    printf("Using this hex string with size %zu bytes: \n %s \n", hex_length, hex);
    
    unsigned char bin[hex_length/2];
    size_t maxsize = sizeof(bin);
    size_t binsize;
    printf("sizeof result for bin: %zu \n", binsize);
    
    int status = sodium_hex2bin(bin, maxbinsize, hex, phex_length, NULL, &binsize, &end);
    if(status < 0) {
        printf("Error %d target: bin seems not large enough\n", status);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Converted Binary is: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < binsize; i++)
    {
        printf("%02hhx ", bin[i]);
    }
    putc('\n');

    return 0;
}
```